# Is text-align cropping images in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have two obscenely large PNGs that are severely scaled down and put in a `div`, centered both horizontally and vertically. The horizontal centering is achieved with `text-align: center` in the CSS for the page, and everything seems to be working fine for the most part... in Chrome.

[image: Freehand arrows, man.]
[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPNC2/)

In Firefox, two of the images (not all of them) are ever so slightly cropped to the right. Opening the developer toolbox and disabling `text-align: center` (inherited from and applied to large parts of the page) fixes the images for no apparent reason. Just opening the developer toolbox in and of itself makes the left image appear correctly (not the one to the right, however), but it crops again once the toolbox is closed.

Why is this happening? Is this intended behavior? A bug? Have I messed up?

Comment: can you create fiddle of you code

Comment: can you add your html and css too

Comment: Here's the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ZPNC2/

Comment: @Adrift `-moz-crisp-edges` just gives me horrible aliasing. I have a suspicion that switching all of these PNGs for reasonably sized SVGs might solve the problem, but I don't want to go there yet.

Comment: I think those are just artefacts from scaling down. If you make the jsfiddle window wider or smaller, you can see that the rendering differs slightly depending on the window width. Sometimes the cut-off effect is there, sometimes it isn't. I guess scaling them down in a good graphics program isn't an option?

Comment: @MrLister The reason the images are extremely large is for scalability's sake. SVGs would solve this, though. The only problem with that, however, is I don't know how widespread SVG support is in commonly / uncommonly used browsers.

Comment: If you want to know how widespread any feature is, use caniuse.com. In this case, http://caniuse.com/#search=svg says IE 9, Firefox 3, Chrome 5, Safari 3, Opera 9, etc. I think you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you. I am, however, still very confused as to why this scaling problem is present with `text-align: center` and not without.

Comment: Rounding errors. If you make the jdfiddle window wider or narrower, the result changes from perfect circles to sliced-off ones and back. And this happens both with and without `text-align:center`, only at different widths.

Comment: @MrLister There's the answer! Rounding errors. I would love it if you posted it as an answer, so this question can be marked done with.

Comment: @LpSamuelm Yes. In fact, I just thought of an actual solution. So, you're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no cropping going on. If you resize the jsfiddle window slightly, you will see that  the result changes from perfect circles to sliced-off ones and back.

[image: left: cut off; right: whole]

(This is enlarged for better visibility; unfortunately you can't get the same result by zooming in on your browser!)

So, it's just rounding errors.
As you can see however, the rounding error only occurs at the far right of the picture, at or around the right edge.

So there is an easy solution: make the images a bit larger, so that the edges of the shapes are no longer at the edges of the pictures. I put some padding on the left side as well, to ensure that the shapes stay in the center.
See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/ZPNC2/1/) with the new images:

```
<div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFpjU.png" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WucxK.png" />
</div>
```